# I can't get Google Colab to read my class

Tags: python, class, upload, google-colaboratory

I'm working with Google Colab on a Python project. I would like to load a class, but as soon as I allocate the instance it doesn't see it. How is it possible?
The error is: *Name 'Class' is not defined*.
In particular, I should load a class with its dictionary.

I expect Google Colab to know how to "read" the classes I load externally.

Comment: Would it be possible that you edit your post with a sample of your code ?

Comment: Now I solved it by inserting all the code of the class directly in Colab, thanks anyway